# What is happening with torch.Tensor.add_?

Tags: pytorch

I'm looking at this implementation of SGD for PyTorch: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD

And I see some strange calculations which I don't understand.

For instance, take a look at `p.data.add_(-group['lr'], d_p)`. It makes sense to think that there is a multiplication of the two parameters, right? (It's how SGD works, `-lr * grads`)

But the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.add) of the function doesn't say anything about this.

And what is more confusing, although this SGD code actually works (I tested by copying the code and calling prints below the `add_`), I can't simply use `add_` with two arguments as it does:

```
#this returns an error about using too many arguments 
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
b = torch.tensor([6,10,15])
c = torch.tensor([100,100,100])
a.add_(b, c)
print(a)
```

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for scalars:

```
a = t.tensor(1)
b = t.tensor(2)
c = t.tensor(3)
a.add_(b, c)
print(a)
```

> tensor(7)

Or `a` can be a tensor:

```
a = t.tensor([[1,1],[1,1]])
b = t.tensor(2)
c = t.tensor(3)
a.add_(b, c)
print(a)
```

> tensor([[7, 7],
>           [7, 7]])

Output is 7, because: `(Tensor other, Number alpha)`